# Running Integration Testing with WebApplicationFactory throws CancellationTokenSource has been disposed on Test Class Cleanup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, xunit

I have a few Web Api Controller tests. These are built with the WebApplicationFactory provided by .NET Core Tests.

- When I run these Controller tests one-by-one, they all pass.
- When I run these Controller test all at once (in Visual Studio, right click the Test-project and choose "Run Tests") all the tests fail, except randomly one.

**Print-screen 1**: all success

[image: All tests success one by one]

**Print-screen 2**: all failed, except one:

[image: all failed, except one]

All the tests consists of a [Theory] passing in MemberData to test various security combinations.

```
7)  Project.UserRolesControllerTests.GetUserDetailsById_ReturnsConfiguredResult
  Duration: 1 ms

  Message: 
    [Test Class Cleanup Failure (Project.Controllers.UserRolesControllerTests)]: System.ObjectDisposedException : The CancellationTokenSource has been disposed.
  Stack Trace: 
    CancellationTokenSource.ThrowObjectDisposedException()
    RedisStorage.Dispose()
    Disposer.Dispose(Boolean disposing) line 38
    Disposable.Dispose() line 32
    LifetimeScope.Dispose(Boolean disposing) line 414
    Disposable.Dispose() line 32
    Container.Dispose(Boolean disposing) line 142
    Disposable.Dispose() line 32
    AutofacServiceProvider.Dispose() line 121
    WebHost.Dispose()
    WebApplicationFactory`1.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
    WebApplicationFactory`1.Dispose()
```

I have found a [Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/39911) on the Dotnet Runtime project [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/39911). However, I'm not sure it's the same issue. Also, I can't seem to get the workaround fixed.

Any one has experience with this? I can run these tests manually for now, but it will also be part of the CI pipeline on DevOps. I persume it will break there as well.

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: add used code

```
public class MyCustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>
    : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
{
    private UserConfiguration _userConfiguration;

    public void SetUser(UserConfiguration userConfiguration)
    {
        _userConfiguration = userConfiguration;
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);

        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Statistics:RedisDb", "<conn. string>");

        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter()); // Remove entire JWT-requirement for all controllers during test
            });
            services.AddScoped<IJwtService>(instance =>
            {
                var customJwtService = new CustomJwtService(() => _userConfiguration);

                return customJwtService;
            });
            services.AddScoped<IHttpRequestHeaderService>(instance =>
            new CustomHttpRequestHeaderService(() => _userConfiguration));
        });

        builder.UseEnvironment("Test");
    }
}

public class CommunityPostsControllerTests : IClassFixture<MyCustomWebApplicationFactory<CommunityPostsController>>
{
    private MyCustomWebApplicationFactory<CommunityPostsController> _factory;

    public CommunityPostsControllerTests(MyCustomWebApplicationFactory<CommunityPostsController> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<object[]> RoleAccess => new List<object[]>
    {
        new object[] { UserConfigurations.AdminCi1, Ci1EmployeePostInGroup, HttpStatusCode.OK},
        new object[] { UserConfigurations.EmployeeCi1, Ci1ParentPostInGroup, HttpStatusCode.Forbidden},
        // Omitted for readability
    };

    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(RoleAccess))]
    public async Task GetPostById_ReturnsConfiguredResult(UserConfiguration userConfiguration, int communityPostId, HttpStatusCode expectedCode)
    {
        // Arrange
        _factory.SetUser(userConfiguration);
        var client = _factory.CreateClient();

        // Act
        var result = await client.GetAsync($"api/v1/communityposts/{communityPostId}", cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(expectedCode, result.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

Edit: CI result

As expected, the Azure DevOps CI pipeline also encounters this issue. Below is the log/result:

```
Microsoft(R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.7.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...

A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured.Key { 8ad52f98 - 5736 - 4d40 - 85b9 - e758dd2823e4}
may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {fd541f11-452b-4089-afd4-5f8cf81c43af} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
  [xUnit.net 00:00:46.30][Test Class Cleanup Failure(Project.WebApi.IntegrationTests.Controllers.CommunityPostsControllerTests)] System.ObjectDisposedException
X Project.WebApi.IntegrationTests.Controllers.CommunityPostsControllerTests.GetPostById_ReturnsConfiguredResult [1ms]
Error Message:
   [Test Class Cleanup Failure(Project.WebApi.IntegrationTests.Controllers.CommunityPostsControllerTests)]: System.ObjectDisposedException : The CancellationTokenSource has been disposed.
  Stack Trace:
     at System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.ThrowObjectDisposedException()
   at Hangfire.Pro.Redis.RedisStorage.Dispose()
   at Autofac.Core.Disposer.Dispose(Boolean disposing) in / home / appveyor / projects / autofac / src / Autofac / Core / Disposer.cs:line 38
   at Autofac.Util.Disposable.Dispose() in / home / appveyor / projects / autofac / src / Autofac / Util / Disposable.cs:line 32
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.Dispose(Boolean disposing) in / home / appveyor / projects / autofac / src / Autofac / Core / Lifetime / LifetimeScope.cs:line 414
   at Autofac.Util.Disposable.Dispose() in / home / appveyor / projects / autofac / src / Autofac / Util / Disposable.cs:line 32
   at Autofac.Core.Container.Dispose(Boolean disposing) in / home / appveyor / projects / autofac / src / Autofac / Core / Container.cs:line 142
   at Autofac.Util.Disposable.Dispose() in / home / appveyor / projects / autofac / src / Autofac / Util / Disposable.cs:line 32
   at Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacServiceProvider.Dispose() in / home / appveyor / projects / autofac - extensions - dependencyinjection / src / Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection / AutofacServiceProvider.cs:line 121
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.Dispose()
Results File: /home/vsts/work/_temp/_fv-az6-181_2020-11-02_12_27_22.trx

Test Run Failed.
Total tests: 49
     Passed: 48
     Failed: 1
```

EDIT: Package configs

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing" Version="2.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.3.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: How does your tests look like?

Comment: I've updated the post with usage.

Comment: Can you update to a newer version of xUnit? Maybe it is a known issue and already fixed...

Comment: @mu88 Sadly not... I added packages & versions to the post.

Comment: Why are you passing `CommunityPostsController` into the generic of `MyCustomWebApplicationFactory`? This should be your `Startup` class and not your controller. I'm not sure if that's the problem, but you should probably update that.

Answer (score 1):

`IAsyncDisposable` support [was added](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/commit/5ccc7401c483295dec1fac215c6e3fc7cd11a70b) to `WebApplicationFactory` on Jun 9, 2021. I think this means you can call `DisposeAsync()` instead of `Dispose()`, which, at least for me, seems to solve the problem.

Before:

```cs
[ClassCleanup]
public static void ClassCleanup()
{
    _webApplicationFactory.Dispose();
}
```

After:

```cs
[ClassCleanup]
public static async Task ClassCleanup()
{
    await _webApplicationFactory.DisposeAsync();
}
```

Comment: [ClassCleanup] is not available anymore

Answer (score 1):

In this case I added the `IAsyncLifetime` interface to the test class and implemented:

```
public async Task DisposeAsync()
{
   await _webApplicationFactory.DisposeAsync();   
}
```

prevents the error to happen. A nice explanation can be found [async lifetime with xunit](https://mderriey.com/2017/09/04/async-lifetime-with-xunit/)

Answer (score 0):

One reason this can happen when running XUnit is that XUnit runs all tests in parallel (except the one in the same class or collection). WebApplicationFactory can mess this up a bit.

A solution is to mark all your test classes with a collection with the same name. This means that all test classes that exists in the same collection with that name not will run in parallel.

```
[Collection("DisableParallelRun")]
public class YourTestClass
```

Source: https://xunit.net/docs/running-tests-in-parallel

Note! This will of course make your tests run slower since they now doesn't run in parallel...